# Multiple-column index would also be useful for single column?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm confused about the order on multiple indexes groups.

Take a look at this:

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

Well in query above I have to create a three-column index on `(col1, col2, col3)`. Now I want to know, that multiple-index is useful elsewhere? For example this query:

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?
```

Should I create another two-column index `(col1, col2)` for this ^ or that three-column index is enough here too?

---

And what about this query:

```
. . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

Or this one:

```
. . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col1 = ?
```

Do all of them need separated indexes or one multiple index is enough for all of them?

In fact I'm trying to understand how the order of indexes work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL has good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the use of multi-column indexes.

The first thing to note is that your `where` conditions consist of equal conditions; also type conversions and collation differences can affect the use of indexes.  The conditions are also connected by `AND`.  `OR` impedes the use of an index.

From the perspective of indexing, the order of the columns (with equality) does not matter.  So, for these conditions:

```
WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

Any of these six indexes are optimal:  `(col1, col2, col3)`, `(col1, col3, col2)`, `(col2, col1, col3)`, `(col2, col3, col1)`, `(col3, col1, col2)`, and `(col3, col2, col1)`.  They "cover" the `where` clause.

As a side note:  at most one inequality can use an index optimally, and that is the last column used in the index.

That `where` clause can also make use of smaller indexes, such as `(col1)`, or `(col2, col3)`.  In this case, some filtering is done using the index and for the rest, the engine needs to look up data in the data pages to fetch the needed fields.

An index can also be used for `where` conditions that use just a subset of the keys -- but the keys have to be used from left to right.  So, an index on `(col1, col2, col3)` can be used for these conditions:

```
where col1 = ? and col2 = ? and col3 = ?
where col1 = ? and col2 = ?
where col2 = ? and col1 = ?
where col1 = ?
```

It won't be used for conditions that don't have `col3`.  And, it can be used (partially) for a condition such as:

```
where col1 = ? and col2 = ? and col4 = ?
```

Comment: Great explanations .. Thx +1

Comment: So an index on `(col1, col2, col3)` can be used for these condition `where col2 = ?` ?

Comment: @Stack . . . No.  The columns in the index are used left-to-right.  So, you need a condition on `col1` before you can use `col2`.

Comment: So there is a paradox in your answer ... You said `(col1, col2, col3)` can be used for `where col2 = ? and col1 = ?` *(third one)* ..!

Comment: @Stack . . . In other words, the ordering of the conditions in the `where` clause doesn't matter (as long as they are connected by `and`).  The ordering in the index *does* matter.

Comment: I see completely. Just my last question, What do you mean of that **a side note**? Do you mean where there is a lot of different conditions, I have to  creating separate single index for each column rather composite index?

Comment: @Stack . . . These rules apply to equality conditions.  When you have other conditions (`<>`, `<`, `>`, `in`, `not in` for example), the index can only make optimal use of one of those -- and it needs to be the last key used in the index.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand "last key" .. Like this? index: `(col1, col2, col3)`, condition: `where col3 > ?`? because `col3` is last one

Comment: @Stack . .  . Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did you mean: "It won't be used for conditions that don't have **`col1`**"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Composite index **only** from left to right.

so if you have a index on col1, col2, col3

**it works for**

```
col1, col2 , col3
col1, col2
col1
```

**but not for**

```
col2, col3
col3
```

**sample**

i have create a table with 3 columns and 10000 rows

```
INSERT INTO tab3
SELECT NULL,seq,seq+1,seq+2 FROM seq_1_to_10000;
```

**EXPLAIN without index**

```
MariaDB []> explain select * from tab3 where col1 = 100 AND col2 = 101 AND col3 = 102;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tab3  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9991 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

**create index over 3 columns**

```
MariaDB []> ALTER TABLE tab3 add key idx_tab3 (col1,col2,col3);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.27 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**try select again, use only 1 ROW**

```
MariaDB []> explain select * from tab3 where col1 = 100 AND col2 = 101 AND col3 = 102;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tab3  | ref  | idx_tab3      | idx_tab3 | 15      | const,const,const |    1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**try WHERE with col1 and col2, also works**

```
MariaDB []> explain select * from tab3 where col1 = 100 AND col2 = 101;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tab3  | ref  | idx_tab3      | idx_tab3 | 10      | const,const |    1 | Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**try WHERE with col1 and col3, not works perfect**

```
MariaDB []> explain select * from tab3 where col1 = 100 AND col3 = 102;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tab3  | ref  | idx_tab3      | idx_tab3 | 5       | const |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just is that three-column index useful for this: `col1, col3` ?

Comment: you can easy see it with a EXPLAIN before your select

Comment: @Stack - i have add a Sample in my Answer

Answer (score 2):

As you have index created on `(col1, col2, col3)` it should work fine for the below cases since for those two condition `col1` is the first key in the index

```
. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?

. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?
```

But `. . . WHERE col2 = ? AND col3 = ?` OR `WHERE col2 = ? AND col1 = ?` would not work likewise. In this case, you have to create a separate index though.

But in your case, I feel it would be best if you go for creating separate single index for each column rather composite index.

Comment: I see, thx +1 ..! Just `(col1, col2, col3)` works for `. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?` ?

Comment: @Stack, Yes it will.

Comment: Are you sure? `:)` because there isn't `col2` on the `WHERE` clause. Have you read it carefully?

Comment: @Stack, Yes I am pretty sure and yes I read question before posting answer.

Comment: Ah thx `:-)`. Just to be sure, lemme ask it again *(I'm obsession a bit)*: this index `(col1, col2, col3)` works for `. . . WHERE col1 = ? AND col3 = ?` ?

Comment: @Stack, My bad, let me re-call what I said before. No, this where condition won't use index since `col2` missing altogether.